# Sticky faucet handle of unrecognized faucet

Tags: leak, faucet

Does anyone recognize the brand of the faucet in the image below, so that I can attempt to disassemble and inspect parts? Secondly, the right-hand handle sticks; is hard to turn off completely, and leaves water leaking from the spout.  Any advice on how to fix this problem?

[image: faucet]

Comment: there may be labels attached to the pipes underneath ... you have said what type of valves you have (compression or washerless) (washreless would be 1/4 or 1/2 turn with hard stops)

Comment: Tommie, you can discontinue the practice of adding the comment notice at the top of your questions. That goes without saying on SE networks. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks much like [this one](https://www.faucet.com/newport-brass-1090-antique-brass-alexandria-double-handle-widespread-lavatory-faucet-with-metal-lever-handles/f26851)--wow ... not cheap--found by doing a web image search for "antique brass faucet".

[This is the install document](https://s1.img-b.com/faucet.com/mediabase/specifications/newport_brass/55636/newport-brass-1090-installation-1490.pdf). Item 16 is a setscrew that you loosen so that you can remove the handle, and expose the cartridge assembly. Then I guess that you would loosen a retaining ring and pull up on the cartridge assembly.

**Do not forget to shut off the water before doing this.**

[Here is the manufacturer](https://newportbrassfaucets.com/?page=products&action=view&categoryID=95&manufacturerID=12&productID=1090). You could email them.

[Here is a search for info](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=newport%20brass%20how%20to%20replace%20cartridge&atb=v16&ia=videos).

Comment: Could you offer any advice on part two of the question (how to disassemble, inspect, and clean these faucets)?  - I'm a novice in this area but I'm handy and learn quick.

Comment: This answer addresses the critical points of disassembly. Cleaning of a faucet mostly involves dissolving calcium buildup. However, cartridge-type faucets generally don't need much cleaning if the cartridges are being replaced. There's plenty to be found on that with a search.